# Sublime sidebar create a custom menu

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there some way to add a new menu to the sidebar?

Right now, I have the following menus in the sidebar:

- OPEN FILES
- FOLDERS

Would it be possible to add a new custom menu above those two that would then have multiple child-menus? These child-menus would be used to run various commands or scripts that would manipulate the selected text or the currently open file.

For example:

- MY CUSTOM MENU

  - Sort selected text
  - Insert gibberish text
  - Open command prompt
- OPEN FILES
- FOLDERS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's possible to add context menu entries to the files and folders that appear in the side bar already, the side bar is not customizable such that you can add new sections or content, or even change the order of the items that already appear.